# Algorithm: single quote non-matching pattern

Tags: java

I have a problem where I will have a template like:

```
"Tada lala at ha on EEEE (MMM d)."
```

which needs to be passed to DateTimeFormatter.format()

So we need to quote the literal text like

```
" 'Tada lala at' ha 'on' EEEE (MMM d)."
```

so the date pattern could evolve with time:

```
"ha 'on' EEEE 'tada lala at' ha 'on' MMM, d"
```

I am showing the real code that uses:

```
Date myDate; // which I just computed.
String template = getTemplateFromDB();//" 'Tada lala at' ha 'on' EEEE (MMM d)."
String formattedStr = DateTimeFormatter(date, template);
```

So by evolving I mean the template string will be evolved but it will reside in the database so the code will not be coupled.

So I need to find an algorithm which will put only literal texts in single quote but leave the date patterns such as (EEEE) alone. What is the best performing algorithm to accomplish this?

I have a draft algorithm:

```
String myRegEx = "(EEEE|MMM|d|...)";
ArrayList<Integer> positionsFound; // a list that is populated with the index positions of the myRegEx patterns are located.

String[] splittedText = myStr.split(); // " 'Tada lala at' ha 'on' EEEE (MMM d)."

StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0;i < splittedText.length;i++) {
    if (!positionsFound.contains(i)) {
        splittedText[i] = "'"+splittedText[i]+"'";
    }
    sbuf.append(splittedText[i]+" ");
}

return sbuf.toString();
```

Comment: In general, this isn't a solvable problem (at least without further constraints).  How is the algorithm supposed to know which part of the string to leave alone?

Comment: This is a bit perplexing.  If the format evolves over time, then that's a good time to deal with its changes; otherwise, you're just building in lots of spaghetti code which may not ever be needed.  Unless that is, you can actually demonstrate *real* uses of the alternate patterns.

Comment: I have added real code to demonstrate the use case.

Comment: @Oliver, I already explained that. Because we already know the patterns for DateTimeFormatter ie EEE, MMM, etc. So anything other than those are  the texts to leave alone.

Comment: Why do those bits need quoting?

Comment: @Oliver, check the DateTimeFormatter class documentation:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html check the table for the row corresponding to literal text.

Comment: @Oliver, again it is not really the question of DateTimeFormat actually. The real question is the generic problem: quote the parts of text that are non-matching.

Comment: But *why* do you think those delimiters are necessary?

Comment: I already explained: when the DateTimeFormatter sees the limiters it considers them as literal text and leaves alone.

Comment: Ok, I'll get directly to the point :)  The quoting is necessary because it's impossible for DateTimeFormat to distinguish between literal text and special characters - how is it supposed to know whether (e.g.) `d` is a literal `d` or the special character `d`?  The same would apply for any preprocessing routine too.

Comment: @Oliver, you almost got me with this. Here it goes - if we can make sure the regEx pattern "d" falls within word boundary then your case will not be valid at all because there is no word such as "d". So if the regex matcher is looking for the pattern "d" within word boundary then it will not match any literal text ie "dog" will not match but only "d" will match. And this applies for other patterns ie EEE, MMM, etc too. Only exception is "ha" for "4PM" so we have to handle it differently.